# Dual Citizen Lebanese - Russian Travelling to Thailand

Tags: visas, thailand, dual-nationality, russian-citizens, lebanese-citizens

I am dual citizen (Lebanon/Russia) permanently residing in Lebanon.
I would like to go to Thailand on my Russian passport because Russians get a 30 day visa on arrival in Thailand, while Lebanese don't.

My question is:

1. When I leave Lebanon, I should show to the authorities my Lebanese passport.
2. When I first land in Thailand, is it enough to show my Russian passport, even though it doesn't contain any exit stamp from Lebanon? Or will immigration cause my problems?

Comment: Is it an option for you to show both passports when coming back to Lebanon?

Comment: yes. Russians get 90 days visa on arrival in lebanon. I had just come back from thailand and I asked the authorities: It is perfectly fine to come back in on another passport, as long as I fill in the on arrival card.

Comment: alright I see, but does it mean you then have to leave Lebanon in the next 90 days?

Comment: Yes. But that is fine. I don’t mind leaving it anwy.

Comment: Fair enough. By the way, you can answer your own question in the "Your Answer" field below. It is even recommended, see http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/answering-my-own-question

Comment: @AdrienBe in general, a citizen of a country should (and in some cases must) use the passport of that country to enter that country.  Why would the OP enter Lebanon with a Russian passport?  I have never entered Lebanon, but no other country I've ever entered looked for exit stamps for the country I was traveling from.

Comment: @phoog my suggestion was to simply present the two passports when coming back to Lebanon. Showing a proof that he didn't need a visa for Thailand (as he has a Russian passport) nor he needs a visa for Lebanon (as he also has a Lebanon passport). However, things might be much more complicated than that, I do not know.

Comment: @AdrienBe Do you mean show to the airline?  I assumed you meant show to the border guard.  But why then the talk about having 90 days in Lebanon?  The OP is a Lebanese citizen; he would not have any limit to his stay in Lebanon.

Comment: @phoog yeah I meant show both at the custom and directly ask them what he can do really. But nevermind, bytebuster did come up with a pretty thorough answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, a small correction. Citizens of Russia have [**visa exemption**](http://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand/changes-visa-exempt.php) which lets them visit Thailand for up to 30 days on tourist purposes with *no need of visa*. This is different than a Visa on Arrival when you actually get visa stamped at the booth in the airport building.

Indeed, many countries require their citizens to provide local passports crossing the local border. E.g., if you have dual citizenship of Russia and Lebanon, you always need to cross the border of Lebanon with your Lebanese passport, while crossing the border of Russia with the Russian passport only.

This is a known practice, and the immigration officers are aware about the case, so the best sequence is as follows:

- Leave Lebanon with your Lebanese passport;
- Just show your Russian passport when entering the Kingdom of Thailand;
- In most cases, you will never be asked for any exit stamps;
- If being asked, just show up your Lebanese passport;
- Keep your arrival/departure card with your Russian passport;

When traveling back:

- Show up your Lebanese passport when checking in for a return flight (since your air ticket is issued for a Lebanese passport);
- At the immigration booth, show up your Russian passport and arrival card and get an exit stamp;

---

One more thought. If you are an active traveler, you may be concerned of **preserving free pages** in your passports. Russian passport takes up to 6 months to be made and takes a lot of effort and paperwork, so obviously it is better to save free pages there.
So if time permits, consider obtaining a normal **Thai tourist visa in your Lebanese passport**.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing response mate. 
P.S. It requires 2 to 3 month for me to get a new russian passport from the lebanese consulate. Just checked that today :)

Comment: BTW, The blog link is a valid concern, though it depends on residency. I'm not resident in russia, so it doesn’t apply to me. Same for military service and taes etc..

Comment: One more thing, when leaving lebanon, I should use the russian passport with the airline right?

Comment: I assume that the air ticket is issued to your Lebanese passport, right? If so, you don't need your Russian passport till you have arrived to Thailand. Yet another problem may occur if the airline would check if you're eligible to visit the country of destination (because if you are not, **the airline would be responsible** for sending you back). I would suggest checking this with the airline upon purchasing tickets.

Comment: yeah, without thai visa on the lb passport, they will nag. So I need to use my Russian passport for airline, and lebanese for customs.

Comment: @turgon in my experience air tickets are not issued to a passport, but to a person.  Airlines do not care which passport I use to identify myself with.  They only care that (1) I *can* identify myself, and (2) I have the documents I need to enter my destination country.  I therefore show my US passport when I fly to the US and my EU passport when I fly to the EU.  No airline employee has ever batted an eye.

Comment: @phoog well the passports serves to identify if u can land in the country of destination. US citiens get 3 month on arrival in EU and visa versa. 
Try going to Russia on the US passport and they will ask to see a visa ;)

Comment: @turgon that's my point.  If I had Russian/US citizenship, I would show my Russian passport when flying to Russia and my US passport when flying to the US.  The airline would not care what passport (if any) I had given them when I booked the ticket.